# jQuery fiter function with ID and class as variables

Tags: jquery

I try to make filter function in jquery.
I have two variables in jquery: rowid and realclass. They both are with right values. I try to use my filter function:

```
$("input").filter('"#" + rowid .realclass').show();
```

But this function isn't working. If i use this:

```
$("input").filter("#" + rowid).show();
```

Then everything is fine, but i need to get realclass variable as class in this statement. Any ideas?

Comment: can you share a html sample for the target html.. whether the rowid and the class belongs to the input element

Comment: from what I can see there is no need to use a filter `$('#' + rowid + ' input.' + realclass)` will do

Comment: if the id belongs to the input then only the id selector is enough `$('#' + rowid)`

Comment: Here is answer, i get idea! $("input").filter("#" + rowid + "." + realclass).show();

Comment: really that is not needed `$('#' + rowid).show()` is enough

Comment: I have input element and td element. When click on td it change to input. They both have same id because, just one element is showed on web.

Comment: then your markup is invalid because id of an element must be unique in a document

Comment: rowid is parent object id. class is object class. I a have multiple objects in class, they parent id is the same but classes different!!!

Comment: can you share a html sample of the structure so that we can understand it better

Comment: There is no need for it. I asked  just the for the right syntax. Everything else is fine. And i get my answer! Everything wors fine.

Comment: the problem is I don't think the answer you have is the right one... may be something which works... that does not mean it is the right one

Comment: also even then there is no need to us filter.... try `$("#" + rowid + "." + realclass).show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
$("input").filter("#" + rowid + ".realclass").show();
```

And I think you can directly use it with `id` because an `id` will be the unique in one page

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$("input").filter("#" + rowid +  ".realclass").show();
```

But see, there is no point in doing this kind of process here, since `id` should be unique.